# Random with Math.round in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Trying to find my way through Flutter and really battling.
I have a this in javascript and cant find how to do this in Flutter.

```
var randNumber = this.random();
var pointerValue = (Math.floor(10 / randNumber) * 10) + pinValue ;
```

I can work out that this.random() is new Random() but whats the like method for Math.floor. I only find round but i get the following error The method 'round' isn't defined for the type 'Random'.

Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this method to get random number in flutter.  I have used integer random number with a range 0 of 1000.

```
 int getRandomInt() {
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(1000);
    print("randomNumber-  " + randomNumber.toString() );
    String unique = randomNumber.toString();
    return int.parse(unique);
  }
```

Comment: @Robbal Cool! you can accept my answer as correct one.